# TypeScript: Requesting Values over API but the values are not correct saved

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an API, which delivers status information over specific services from a database (better: log). I am asking for the newest entry in the database per specific service.

My component is this:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, Inject, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {merge, Observable, of as observableOf} from "rxjs";
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";
import { StatusInterface, StatusElementInterface } from '../../interfaces/status.interface';
import {L10N_LOCALE, L10nLocale, L10nTranslationService} from "angular-l10n";
import {catchError, map, startWith, switchMap} from "rxjs/operators";
import {MatPaginator} from "@angular/material/paginator";
import {MatSort} from "@angular/material/sort";
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogConfig} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatFormField, MatLabel  } from '@angular/material/form-field';

@Component({
    selector: 'ptb-status-view',
    templateUrl: './status-view.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './status-view.component.css']
})


export class StatusViewComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    exampleDatabase: ExampleHttpDatabase | null;
    data = {} as StatusInterface;
    isLoadingResults: boolean;
    resultsLength: number;
    routeNotRegistered: boolean = false;
    dataArray = [
        "import",
        //"export",
        "cron",
        "delta"
    ];

    dataResults = {} as StatusInterface;

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

    constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient,
                @Inject(L10N_LOCALE) locale: L10nLocale,
                private translation: L10nTranslationService,
                private dialog: MatDialog) {

        for (var val in this.dataArray) {
            this.dataResults[val] = {} as StatusElementInterface;
        }
    }


    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.exampleDatabase = new ExampleHttpDatabase(this._httpClient);
        var href = '/schuhe-store/status';

        if(environment.production === false) {
            href = 'https://sales.dailysshop.com/schuhe-store/status';
        }

        for(var val of this.dataArray) {

            const requestUrl =
                `${href}?type=${val}`;

            this._httpClient.get<StatusInterface>(requestUrl)
                .pipe(
                map(data => {

                    return data
            })
                )
        .subscribe(data => {

            // @ts-ignore
            this.dataResults[val] = data;
            console.log(this.dataResults[val]);

            }, error => {

                const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

                if (error.status == 404) {

                    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
                    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
                    console.log(error.errno);
                    this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, dialogConfig);
                } else if (error.status = 200) {
                    this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, dialogConfig);
                }
                this.routeNotRegistered = true;
            });

        }

    }
}

/** An example database that the data source uses to retrieve data for the table. */
export class ExampleHttpDatabase {
    constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    getRepoIssues(): Observable<StatusInterface> {
        var href = '/schuhe-store/status';

        if(environment.production === false) {
            href = 'https://sales.dailysshop.com/schuhe-store/status';
        }

        const requestUrl =
            `${href}`;

        return this._httpClient.get<StatusInterface>(requestUrl);
    }
}

export class DialogOverviewExample {

    animal: string;
    name: string;

    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

    openDialog(): void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
            width: '250px',
        });

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            console.log('The dialog was closed');
        });
    }

}

@Component({
    selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
    templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}

    onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }

}

export interface DialogData {
    animal: string;
    name: string;
}
```

My target is, that the specific answer is stored in dataResults as a named index. So I could call the information in the html file like this {{ dataResults['import']['timestamp'] }}, which isn't working. I am getting an error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'timestamp')

My interface is:

```
export interface StatusInterface {
    [key: string]: StatusElementInterface;
}

export interface StatusElementInterface {
    type?: string;
    lastrun?: Date;
    timestamp?: number;
}
```

I don't get it running at any situation. Can someone get this solved?

Kind regards
Henning

Comment: `this.dataResults[val] = data;` should only be `this.dataResults = data;`. (Also the `pipe` is not needed, at least with what the map does in the example.)

Comment: Hi @GunnarB., the val is an loop. I created a new thread with the more specific code to show, what shall happen. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69206768/get-value-from-interface-is-ending-in-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-read)

Comment: What I mean is that you type `get<StatusInterface>`, but assign it to `StatusElementInterface` (this.dataResults[val]). Probably the get should actually be `get<StatusElementInterface>`. Other than that, it's probably just a timing issue as mentioned in the other thread.