# Get Value from Interface is ending in "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'timestamp')"

Tags: angular, typescript

I am pulling information via an API from our system and want to output specific dates and information. The requesting and delivering is working fine:

```
{
    "id": "13963",
    "timestamp": "1631787752",
    "type": "cron",
    "rows": "0",
    "duration": "0"
}
```

My interface looks like this:

```
export interface StatusInterface {
    [key: string]: StatusElementInterface;
}

export interface StatusElementInterface {
    type?: string;
    lastrun?: Date;
    timestamp?: number;
}
```

I am requesting the information from the API in our class likewise:

```
dataArray = [
    "import",
    //"export",
    "cron",
    "delta"
];

dataResults = {} as StatusInterface;
```

In the constructor I am generating the arrays in this way:

```
for (var val in this.dataArray) {
    this.dataResults[val] = {} as StatusElementInterface;
}
```

In ngAfterViewInit I am running a loop in this way:

```
    for(var val of this.dataArray) {

        const requestUrl = `${href}?type=${val}`;

        this._httpClient.get<StatusInterface>(requestUrl)
          .pipe(
            map(data => {
              return data
            })
          )
          .subscribe(data => {

            // @ts-ignore
            this.dataResults[val] = data;
            console.log(this.dataResults[val]);
          }
```

The console output is correct and when I try to display it in the HTML file with `dataResults["delta"]` I get an `[Object object]` and when I try to do `dataResults["delta"]["timestamp"]` I get the error of an `undefined` property.

Can someone adjust me, what's running false or where my error is?

The Javascript log is

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'timestamp')
    at StatusViewComponent_Template (status-view.component.html:18)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:9599)
    at refreshView (core.js:9465)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10636)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9261)
    at refreshView (core.js:9515)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10590)
    at refreshView (core.js:9489)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10636)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9261)
```

My template in the html looks so now:

```
        <mat-list-item>
            <mat-icon mat-list-icon>done</mat-icon>
            <div mat-line>Cronjob</div>
            <div mat-line *ngIf="cronTimestamp">Zuletzt beendet: {{ cronTimestamp | date:"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" }} Uhr</div>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>
            <mat-icon mat-list-icon>done</mat-icon>
            <div mat-line>Exportprozess</div>
            <div mat-line *ngIf="exportTimestamp">Zuletzt beendet: {{ exportTimestamp | date:"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" }} Uhr</div>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>
            <mat-icon mat-list-icon>done</mat-icon>
            <div mat-line>Deltaexport</div>
            <div mat-line *ngIf="deltaTimestamp; else loading">Zuletzt beendet: {{ deltaTimestamp | date:"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" }} Uhr</div>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>
            <mat-icon mat-list-icon>error</mat-icon>
            <div mat-line>Importprozess</div>
            <div mat-line *ngIf="importTimestamp">Zuletzt beendet: {{ importTimestamp | date:"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" }} Uhr</div>
        </mat-list-item>
```

I defined the getters like this:

```
get deltaTimestamp():number|undefined{
    if (this.dataResults['delta'] && this.dataResults['delta']['timestamp'] !== undefined)
        return (this.dataResults['delta']['timestamp'] * 1000);
    return (undefined);
}

get importTimestamp():number|undefined{
    if (this.dataResults['import'] && this.dataResults['import']['timestamp'] !== undefined)
        return (this.dataResults['import']['timestamp'] * 1000);
    return (undefined);
}

get exportTimestamp():number|undefined{
    if (this.dataResults['export'] && this.dataResults['export']['timestamp'] !== undefined)
        return (this.dataResults['export']['timestamp'] * 1000);
    return (undefined);
}

get cronTimestamp():number|undefined{
    if (this.dataResults['cron'] && this.dataResults['cron']['timestamp'] !== undefined)
        return (this.dataResults['cron']['timestamp'] * 1000);
    return (undefined);
}
```

Only the deltaTimestamp is getting shown.

Kind regards
Henning

Comment: could you write what your console log looks like?

Comment: Hi @JSmith, I added the JS log to the main content! KR Henning

Comment: I meant the one with `console.log(this.dataResults[val])` not the one trying to access the timestamp

Comment: until fetch is completed your array is empty.so you might need to add a condition in your html or avoid initializing array with empty objects

Comment: Hi @JSmith, now it works, I get the timestamp. But to format it by the date-Pipe, I have to multiply it by 1000. Using {{ (dataResults["delta"]?.timestamp*1000) | date }} is resulting in an error "Object is possibly 'undefined'.". Can you point me out?

Comment: maybe you should read stackoverflow guideline this is a different question, please ask a new question. And please mark as answered if that solved your original problem.Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the `// @ts-ignore` it is ignoring your assignation.

now if it's in your html view that you have a problem, you may write `dataResults?.delta?.timestamp` because you have to wait till the object gets populated

still you will have problems if you do computation on the view side, on thing you could do is making a getter like:

```
get deltaTimestamp():number|undefined{
  if (this.dataResults['delta'] && this.dataResults['delta']['timestamp'] !== undefined)
    return (this.dataResults['delta']['timestamp'] * 1000);
  return (undefined);
}
```

then simply write `deltaTimestamp` in your view to access the value.

a more generic way that could work in `ngFor*` would be to use a function like `getTimestamp(key)` where you could access `delta`, `cron` and so on timestamp value.

Comment: Hi @JSmith, now it works, I get the timestamp. But to format it by the date-Pipe, I have to multiply it by 1000. Using {{ (dataResults["delta"]?.timestamp*1000) | date }} is resulting in an error "Object is possibly 'undefined'.". Can you point me out?

Comment: @HenningMöllendorf use aas less computation as possible on your view try setting a getter which multiplies if the value is not undefined. Please mark as answer if that solved your question. This is a totally different question you are asking me

Comment: @HenningMöllendorf I've answered your second question

Comment: Hi @JSmith, this works great, but if I make a copy of it to use it for another value, I don't get the output. I will add the used code in my first post here.

Comment: Hi @jsmith, then the elements could change their row with ngFor. But a generic getTimestamp could work. But it is outputting currently only one value...